# Filter flagging history

Tags: feature-request, flags

The flagging history page displays a sidebar that shows the numbers of each type. My feature request is to allow clicking those numbers to show the actual flags that are waiting for review etc.

It would make it much easier than skimming down the page looking for the flags still in review.